# How to get sum value Of Laravel Database?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am facing problem to get total plan price value by Laravel.
Model Reseller.php

```php
public function clients(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Client', 'resellerId', 'resellerId');
}
```

Model Client.php

```php
function plan(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Plan::class, 'plan_id', 'id');
}
```

Model Plan.php

```php
protected $fillable = [
    'plan_name', 'type', 'plan_price'
];
```

Now I want to get total plan_price of Reseller . I am using Laravel 5.6

Comment: so given a reseller you want the sum of the plan of the clients that belongs to that reseller?

Comment: look into sum() method of the Eloquent models. Sort of Plan()->get()->sum("plan_price")

Comment: `$reseller->clients()->with('plan')->sum('plan_price')` should work or be close it.

Comment: Not working this.

Comment: There is no direct connection between `Reseller` model and `Plan` so you can get the total price of all plans and the clients have wich related to this reseller. is this what you need?

Comment: @A.Dabak Yes I need this.

Comment: what kind of result do  u expects? do u want to get the reseller, and each reseller has total plan_price?

Answer (score 0):

I personally Solve this.

```
\App\Client::get()->where('resellerId', 1)->where('status', 'On')->sum(function ($allclient) {
    return $allclient->plan->plan_price;
});
```